# Shooting at mouse in unity

Tags: unity, c#, rigidbody

I'm using unity and trying to get my bullet to shoot at a target. I am clicking the mouse and I'm wanting to fire my bullet in that direction.

I have gotten the coordinates of the mouse click and tried to compute the vector. Then I've tried instantiate the bullet prefab (which has rigidbody component and is in front of the scene) at my position and then fire it in the direction of the mouse.

I can see that my objects being instantiated in my Hierarchy Pane but can't see anything on the screen!

Not sure if I'm doing the vector thing right (newb here), but if I click on Yoshi's head, I'm getting `(-2.0, -0.4)`. Does this sound right?

Code:

```
void fireBullet(float mousePositionX, float mousePositionY)
    {

        Vector2 position = new Vector2(mousePositionX, mousePositionY);
        position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        bullet.transform.LookAt(position);
        Debug.Log(position);
        bullet.rigidbody2D.AddForce(bullet.transform.forward * 1000);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I even don't know how many times question like this was asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using raycast, from the point of your mouse.

By creating a variable of type hit and it should be equal to

```
Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
```

And then check if the variable is **not** equal to null, which means you hit something and then you can check the tag of the object and do what ever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on mobile, so excuse me if I miss some syntax, but:

```
float speed = 1000;
Vector2D mousePosition = GetMousePosition();
Vector2D bulletPosition = GetBulletPosition();
Vector2D direction = (mousePosition - bulletPosition).normalized;
bullet.rigidbody2D.AddForce(direction * speed);
```

Where `GetMousePosition()` and `GetBulletPosition()` retrieve their respective positions.